# Correct way for accessing final fields in java from other class

Tags: java, performance, oop, final

What is the good way to access final fields from other class and why.

A) Isolating it from other class by making it private and giving the functionality in the getter and setter method

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
 private final Racquet racquet;

 public Game() {
    racquet = new Racquet(this);
 }
}

public class Ball {
 private Game game;

 Ball(final Game game) {
    this.game = game;
 }

 void move(int speed) {
    if (collision()) {
        y = game.getRacquet().getTopY() - DIAMETER;
    } 
 }
}

public class Racquet {
 final Game game;

 public Racquet(final Game game) {
    this.game = game;
 }

 public int getTopY() {
    return Y;
 }
}
```

B) Keeping it default and use the variable.methodname directly.

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
 final Racquet racquet;
}

public class Ball {

 void move(int speed) {
  if (collision()) {
   y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
  } 
 }
}

public class Racquet {
 final Game game;

 public Racquet(final Game game) {
 this.game = game;
 }

 public int getTopY() {
 return Y;
 }
}
```

do accessing final fields directly leads to improved performance?

Comment: I like you should have methods in the Racquet class to move it, ex. move up, move down, etc. Let the method do the work internally

Comment: Please check the line y = game.getRacquet().getTopY() - DIAMETER; in A and y = game.getRacquet().getTopY() - DIAMETER; in B

Comment: In the ball class your getting an attribute of racket(position) and subtracting the diameter. Pass the ball position to racket and have the method do the work, rather than calling the getter

Comment: You're basically asking "getter or nor" and the answer is that it doesn't matter. Getters get inlined and cost nothing. Strive for good design first (see the answer by S.R., avoid fooling around with other objects' fields, directly or indirectly), use proper algorithms and data structures and the performance is there. Microoptimizations are useful sometimes, but it's the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the getter to move the Racket, it would be best to have a method it do it for you internally.

```
void move(int speed) {
  if (collision()) {
    racket.move(diameter)
   } 
}
//inside racket
public int move(int diameter){
    return this.Y - diameter;
}
```

Or if you want, split the  move into `moveUp`, `moveDown`, etc.. and return the value of the calculation after you pass the diameter. This will be dependent on a number of things, for example, the position of the ball. You can check the position of the ball and decided which method to call and move the racket.

It might be best to think about it realistically.

You could have a `Player` class:

- Responsible for determining the position of the ball.
- Moving the Racket

In reality your `Racket`, won't be aware of where the `Ball` is, or the `Ball` won't be aware your using a `Racket` to hit it, the `Player` is aware of it.

If you want to follow OOP guidelines, then don't access variables directly(i.e public) instead let the methods to do the work for you, and give you the result, it's a method of [Tell, Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html). Keep the getters for display purposes if needed.